# Getting null reference exception when add empty string to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, casting, type-conversion

This is my code..I cant add a null value to the list.Getting null reference exception.how to avoid it

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
 var empPersonal = context.tblEmployeePersonalDetails.Where(x => x.isDelete == false && x.empId == id).First();
lst.Add(empPersonal.gender.ToString() != null ? empPersonal.gender.ToString() :string.Empty);
```

Comment: which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: In almost all cases NullReferenceException is same. Refer [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `NullReferenceException` doesn't mean that the *item* you're adding is `null`. You can add a null string to the list without problems. What the runtime is telling you is that you are trying to access a property on a reference which points to `null`.E.g.: 1) `context` is null, but you are accessing `context.tblEmployeePersonalDetails`, or 2) `empPersonal` is null, but you are accessing `empPersonal.gender`, or 3) `empPersonal.gender` is null, but you are accessing `empPersonal.gender.ToString()`. You might also want to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
var empPersonal = context.tblEmployeePersonalDetails
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.isDelete == false && x.empId == id);
lst.Add(empPersonal != null ? empPersonal.gender.ToString() :string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `empPersonal.gender` is `null`, calling `empPersonal.gender.ToString()` will yield an error.

What you probably meant to write was:

```
lst.Add(empPersonal.gender != null ? empPersonal.gender.ToString() : string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

Change

```
lst.Add(empPersonal.gender.ToString() != null ? empPersonal.gender.ToString() :string.Empty);
```

To

```
lst.Add(empPersonal != null && empPersonal.gender != null ? empPersonal.gender.ToString() :string.Empty);
```

This catches empPersonal is null and the empPersonal.gender is null because both could be null.